# Java XML parser - get proper output

Tags: java, xml, parsing

i need to create a Java program which will read XML file and print node attributes on one line.

The follow XML is the file to process:

```
<TPVLog version="6.0">
<Snapshot time="1427376440905">
<Stats name="jvmRuntimeModule" statType="jvmRuntimeModule#" il="-2" type="COLLECTION">
<CS id="2" sT="1422004481541" lST="1427376440605" ct="234457">
</CS>
<CS id="3" sT="1422004481541" lST="1427376440605" ct="494333">
</CS>
<CS id="5" sT="1422004481541" lST="1427376440605" ct="0">
</CS>
</Stats>
<Stats name="systemModule" statType="systemModule" il="-2" type="MODULE">
<CS id="1" sT="1427192170123" lST="1427376470956" ct="61">
</CS>
</Stats>
</Snapshot>
</TPVLog>
```

I need to print out from jvmRuntimeModule row cs id="3" value ct 
and from systemModule value ct from cs id="1" on one row.

I was trying to get results via:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
import org.dom4j.XPath;

public class DOM4JParserDemo {


         public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
         File inputFile = new File("tpv_as_aexwidget_1_1427376430227_1.xml");
         SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
         Document document = reader.read( inputFile );



         Element root = document.getRootElement();
for (Element snapshotElement : (List<Element>) root.elements("Snapshot")) {
XPath xpath=snapshotElement.createXPath("Stats[@name='connectionPoolModule']/RS[@id='9']/@cur");
  System.out.printf("%s",xpath.evaluate(document.getRootElement()));
  System.out.println("************** END ************************");
}



}
}
```

or

```
for (Element snapshotElement : (List<Element>) root.elements("Snapshot")) {
    System.out.printf("Value: %s%s%s",
      snapshotElement.selectObject("Stats[@name='jvmRuntimeModule']/CS[@id='2']/@ct"),
      snapshotElement.selectObject("Stats[@name='systemModule']/CS[@id='1']/@ct"),
      snapshotElement.selectObject("Stats[@name='connectionPoolModule']/RS[@id='9']/@cur")
    ).println();
  System.out.println("*****************************************");
}
```

But i am still having output with print number of rows equal to number of Snapshots in file but values are null. 
I have not much experience with Java so i would like to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason for writing this code in Java is if you happen to know Java well and haven't got time to learn languages such as XSLT and XQuery that are designed expressly for this kind of task. Since you aren't an expert in Java, that reason doesn't apply to you.

I'm not sure exactly how you want the output to look, but you could start by running the following XQuery:

```
//Snapshot/concat(
   Stats[@name="jvmRuntimeModule"]/CS[@id='3']/@ct, 
   '&#xa;',
   Stats[@name="systemModule"]/CS[@id='1']/@ct)
```

No need for any Java code at all.

Comment: It's on AIX and to use Java was easiest  for me because in Python or Perl i was not able to build something able to work.  For output i just need to get all values on one row via System.out.printf